# Dependency Injection on Custom Doctrine Repository

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dependency-injection, repository

I've come across two methods to inject dependencies into custom Doctrine Repositories.

1. https://juriansluiman.nl/article/142/dependency-injection-in-a-doctrine-repository
2. http://blog.tomhanderson.com/2016/01/dependency-injection-in-doctrine.html

I understand method one in that it no longer uses the Entity Manager to retrieve the repository and instead uses the service manager.

However, I do not understand method two.  There are two parts I do not understand.  The first is the "Configuration" section.  What does the Doctrine configuration key "repository_factory" do?

```
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'configuration' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'repository_factory' => 'Db\Repository\RepositoryFactory',
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'service_manager' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Db\Repository\RepositoryFactory' => 'Db\Repository\RepositoryFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Then second, I am not sure how to retrieve the repository.  Am I still supposed to use the entity manager?  Or should I use the service manager as I do in method one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, the second link gives a way to override the default arguments passed to the Repository when it is instantiated.

The primary role of a factory (not only in Symfony, it's a common [design pattern](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html#factory)) is to create instances of one or more classes, rather than instantiate them by yourself through the `new` keyword.

When you call `$em->getRepository('EntityFQCN')`, Doctrine (through the `repository_factory`) looks for an eventual Repository class defined in your Entity (i.e. `@ORM\RepositoryClass(...)`) and return an instance of it, otherwise, if there is no Repository class found for the entity, it returns an instance of the default [EntityRepository](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html), with the specified entity as argument (i.e. `getRepository('EntityFQCN')`).

So, without looking at the link in detail, I think I can say that if you try to implement this alternative, you'll retrieve your repository through the "default" way, i.e. `EntityManager::getRepository('xxxx')`.
The role of this configuration part will be to instantiate the Repository differently than the default one.

I already overridden the RepositoryFactory when I needed to override the default `EntityRepository` (return an instance of a custom Repository class without define it in my entities, in other words replace the default Repository class).
You can [see it in action](https://gist.github.com/chalasr/77be8eee5e3ecd3c06ec#file-enhancedrepositoryfactory-php).

Hope you have a lot of fun with DI in Doctrine.

Comment: So I assume that means for every possible repository I'd like to inject dependencies into I would need a similar clause `if (is_subclass_of($entityNamespace, '\App\Util\Doctrine\Entity\EntityInterface', true)) {` in this single file.  I would also have to have all of my `use` statements in a single file for every repository I wish to inject dependencies into.  I feel it would be more modular to use the first method.  Is there ever a reason to use one method over the other?  Or is it simply preference?